# Javascript Alternate functions run onclick

Tags: javascript

So I have this speech to text typing feature that is triggered upon pressing a microphone icon. The feature works.
My problem is that I want the same icon to do 2 things. 
1st click it will start hearing for voice. 2nd click will stop hearing for voice. I basically want the function `onclick` to alternate between 2 functions, Start and Stop. 
How do I do it?

Below is what I got currently. That only works to START the recording
How do I fit `recognition.stop()` into the same click function?

```
$('#micButton').on('click', function () {
    recognition.start(); //this is to start recording
});
```

Below this is what I thought would work (it doesn't), to alternate between start and stop.

```
$('#micButton').on('click',
    function () {
        recognition.start();
    },
    function () {
        recognition.stop();
    }
);
```

To summarise, how do I get my `onclick` to alternate between start and stop?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a flag of some sort to check to see if voice is currently being listened for:

```
let currentlyListening = false;
$('#micButton').on('click', function () {
  if (!currentlyListening) {
    recognition.start(); //this is to start recording
  } else {
    recognition.stop();
  }
  currentlyListening = !currentlyListening;
});
```

It'd probably be good to also provide an indicator to the user the current state as well, if `recognition` doesn't already do that - eg, change or add an image that shows a red dot while `currentlyListening` is `true`.

Comment: Damn. Simple, easy to understand and quick response. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

Could set a data tag or a class to determine if it's being used or not.

```
// SEEING AS YOU'RE USING JQUERY
$('#micButton').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).data('active') == false) {
        recognition.start();
        $(this).data('active', true);
    } else {
        recognition.stop();
        $(this).data('active', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator can be used as well!)

```
$('#micButton').on('click', function () {
  recognition[ this.listening ? "stop" : "start" ]();

  this.listening = !this.listening;
});
```

Nearly the same thing, as @CertainPerformance answer, but storing the true / false flag in the clicked element object.

First click: `this.listening == undefined (false)`, → recognition.start();

Second click: `this.listening == true`, → recognition.stop();

And so on.